# how to add a hook to a custom interactive command

Tags: hooks, notmuch

I have a pipeline that opens an emacs client in `notmuch-mode` when new mail comes in, currently using `(notmuch-show "thread:...")`.
I'd rather use tree view with the most recent message displayed. In two steps this is easy.

1. run `notmuch-thread-view` (automatic)
2. then manually run `notmuch-thread-view-in-tree`.

I'd like for it to be automatic, but I cannot seem to combine the functions. I imagine `notmuch-thread-view-in-tree` runs before `notmuch-thread-view` has filled the buffer. So I think a hook is necessary. But how?

```el
(defun notmuch-thread-view ()
  (interactive)
  (notmuch-tree "thread:0000000000000384")
  ;(notmuch-thread-view-in-tree) ; doesn't work
)

(defun notmuch-thread-view-in-tree ()
  "Open the most recent message in a thread when in tree view.
   will not work for nested threads."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (notmuch-tree-prev-message)
  (notmuch-tree-prev-message)
  (notmuch-tree-show-message-in)
)

; not run?
(add-hook 'notmuch-thread-view 'notmuch-thread-view-in-tree)
; also not helpful
(add-hook 'post-notmuch-thread-view 'notmuch-thread-view-in-tree)
```

Comment: I think you just want an `advice` using `:after`, but since I don't use `notmuch`, I cannot test anything.  See:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions .  There may be no need for a hook per se, unless you plan on adding/removing stuff frequently -- i.e., just run your function `:after` using the `advice`.  If you are running a sub-process and want to execute something when the process ends, then it may be necessary to examine the process filters and/or sentinels to decide where to plug in your custom modification.

Answer (score 2):

> how to add a hook to a custom interactive command

Call one of the `run-hook*` functions, as appropriate.

See:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> `run-hook`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Running Hooks`

That said, I'm doubtful that your question actually helps you.  You've said that calling `(notmuch-thread-view-in-tree)` directly doesn't work, and I don't see how using a hook to do the same thing will make any difference.  If I'm right about that, you should probably ask a separate question and make it more specifically about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

[`notmuch-tree`](https://git.notmuchmail.org/git?p=notmuch;a=blob;f=emacs/notmuch-tree.el;h=c00315e8dd40edaadfc369a95b2545fce49affbf;hb=HEAD#l943) calls [`notmuch-tree-worker`](https://git.notmuchmail.org/git?p=notmuch;a=blob;f=emacs/notmuch-tree.el;h=c00315e8dd40edaadfc369a95b2545fce49affbf;hb=HEAD#l893). `notmuch-tree-worker` starts a `notmuch` process via [`notmuch-start-notmuch`](https://git.notmuchmail.org/git?p=notmuch;a=blob;f=emacs/notmuch-lib.el;h=a7e027101c487c996a45942bb29a6e061a60c446;hb=HEAD#l898).

`notmuch-start-notmuch` assignes the process [`notmuch-start-notmuch-sentinel`](https://git.notmuchmail.org/git?p=notmuch;a=blob;f=emacs/notmuch-lib.el;h=a7e027101c487c996a45942bb29a6e061a60c446;hb=HEAD#l953) as process sentinel.

I think that is the place where you should hook in your `notmuch-thread-view-in-tree` function as `:after` advice with the help of `advice-add`.

I don't use `notmuch` and I am also not willing to install it on my system since a test would imply too much set-up effort on my system.

But something like the following could probably work. Note once again that it is untested.

```el
(defvar my-notmuch-after-thread-view nil)

(defun notmuch-thread-view ()
  (interactive)
  (notmuch-tree "thread:0000000000000384")
  (setq my-notmuch-after-thread-view t)
)

(defun my-notmuch-thread-view-in-tree (proc status)
  "Open the most recent message in a thread when in tree view.
   will not work for nested threads."
  (when (and my-notmuch-after-thread-view
         proc
         (stringp status)
         (string-match "finished" status))
    (setq my-notmuch-after-thread-view nil)
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (notmuch-tree-prev-message)
      (notmuch-tree-prev-message)
      (notmuch-tree-show-message-in))))

(advice-add 'notmuch-start-notmuch-sentinel :after #'my-notmuch-thread-view-in-tree)
```